# SQL - you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql

I am currently using the datasets at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all to learn SQL.

The question I have been given is "Generate a list of all the Customers and the total cost of the Orders they have place – try displaying the total cost to 2 decimal places using the round() function.".

I am entering the code:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, ROUND(sum(CostPerCustomer),2) as "TotalCost"
FROM (
    SELECT c.CustomerName, p.ProductName, (p.Price)*count(c.CustomerName)) AS "CostPerCustomer"
    FROM Customers c, Products p, Orders o, OrderDetails od
    WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID and p.ProductID = od.ProductID and o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    GROUP BY c.CustomerName, p.ProductName
    ORDER BY c.CustomerName, count(c.CustomerName) desc)
GROUP BY CustomerName
```

I receive the error message 'You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'p.Price*count(c.CustomerName)' as part of an aggregate function.'

Is someone please able to tell me what's wrong with my code and how I might fix it?

Comment: edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Comment: This is not an error message returned by Teradata, so why did you add it as a tag?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
    SELECT CustomerName, round(sum(price*Quantity),2) AS TotalCost   FROM Customers C
    JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
    JOIN OrderDetails OD ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
    JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
    GROUP BY CustomerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you join multiple tables and solve the question. The count(c.CustomerName) is not correct here, you have to go the orders table and get all orderid belonging to a customer, then you go to orderdetails table to find what product they have ordered and the quantity. Then you go to the product table and get the price of each product.

```
select c.customerid,c.customername,sum(p.price*od.quantity)
from customers c
join orders o on o.customerid=c.customerid
join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
join products p on p.productid=od.productid
group by c.customerid,c.customername
order by c.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first correct your current query, use of proper explicit `JOIN`s (i.e. `INNER JOIN`)

```
SELECT  
        c.CustomerName, ROUND(SUM(p.Price * od.Qty), 2) AS "TotalCostPerCustomer"
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
GROUP BY c.CustomerName
```